# python duplicated code execution inside of docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

there is something rather strange thing with my code or i just don't understand some python basics

say i have a program that has some libs with function in modules

```bash
myapp.py
mylib # directory
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

each of this modules has function like (for instance foo.py)

```py
fooInstance = None


def bootstrap_foo()
    global fooInstance
    if fooInstance is None:
        logging.info('bootstrapping foo')
        fooInstance = Foo()
    return fooInstance
```

and in other modules i have

```py
import foo
my_foo = bootstrap_foo()
```

and so on

i run code and all works very fine in pycharm but when i try to pack this into docker container with

```
WORKDIR /app

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY myapp.py /app/
COPY mylib/ /app/mylib/

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/app/myapp.py"]
```

and now strange thing happens, in logs i see that code inside of "bootstrap_foo" is executed twice, as if check

```py
if fooInstance is None:
```

doesn't work at all

what is the subtle difference between pycharm & docker in this relation ? some python command line arguments ?

Comment: If two instances of your code are running in different processes, they will each have their own `fooInstance`. I can't see where that would happen here though. If you change the log line to this: `import os; logging.info(f'bootstrapping foo {os.getpid()}')`, are the PIDs the same?

Comment: yes, just tried, it's exactly the case i have different pids for print lines
so any ideas on the reason
?
it's flask application btw: maybe it spins up several processes - all duplication happens before receiving any request ?

Answer (score -1):

two instances of py application when using flask, quite common problem as i later have googled - all due to hot reload mode, after disabling all worked well